# Javascript array changer

Tags: javascript, jquery

How change strings in javascript arrays. I want to change array codes to strings.
How change strings in javascript arrays. I want to change array codes to strings.

How to get this;

```
var _0x1576 = ["SayHello", "GetCount", "Message : ", "You are welcome."];

function NewObject(_0x7aa7x2) {
    var _0x7aa7x3 = 0;
    this.SayHello = function (_0x7aa7x4) {
        _0x7aa7x3++;
        alert(_0x7aa7x2 + _0x7aa7x4);
    };
    this.GetCount = function () {
        return _0x7aa7x3
    };
}
var obj = new NewObject("Message : ");
obj.SayHello("You are welcome.");
```

from;

```
var _0x1576 = ["SayHello", "GetCount", "Message : ", "You are welcome."];

function NewObject(_0x7aa7x2) {
    var _0x7aa7x3 = 0;
    this[_0x1576[0]] = function (_0x7aa7x4) {
        _0x7aa7x3++;
        alert(_0x7aa7x2 + _0x7aa7x4);
    };
    this[_0x1576[1]] = function () {
        return _0x7aa7x3
    };
}
var obj = new NewObject(_0x1576[2]);
obj.SayHello(_0x1576[3]);
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to minify your code

Comment: in which direction would you like to change the strings? from `this.SayHello` to `this[_0x1576[0]]`, or reverse?

Comment: @Nina Scholz  reverse. I want to change "this[_0x1576[0]]" similar codes

Comment: I mean; from `this[_0x1576[0]]` to `this.SayHello`

Comment: i would suggest to use an editor and replace all occurence with the appropriate value.

Comment: So you have code that has been minified/obfuscated and you would like to deobfuscate it, so you can read it?

Comment: This very basic codes. I want to edit my difficult code. This have only 4 array, other script have 800+ array. I can't use this method. How to replace basically? It is have many strings (9k)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: So you have some code, where all the variable names have been replaced by numbers or indices into this global array of names, and you would like to be able to read it. There is already an [answer to this question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4561/how-to-deobfuscate-an-obfuscated-javascript-file-like-this), which contains links to a bunch of useful deobfuscation tools.

Your case here looks fairly trivial - it appears that you could just do a string search and replace, substituting in the array value every time it is indexed. The regexp `/_0x1576\[(\d+)\]/g` should find everything that accesses the variable `_0x1576` with an integer index. The inner group `(\d+)` should give you the index with which it was found. You could use something like this to do deobfuscate your source. However, some of the names have been lost in the obfuscation process; i.e. the name of the parameter `0x7aa7x4` in the `SayHello` function can't be restored. You will have to read the method, understand what its' purpose is, and try to come up with a meaningful name yourself.

One question though - just how much code do you have like this? If there are only a few names in the array of strings, then @Nina Scholz's suggestion seems fairly reasonable. Just go through them one by one, in a text editor, and use the 'Find and Replace' functionality.

Comment: No. I don't want do this. I mean; from `this[_0x1576[0]]` to `this.SayHello`